# Rails 3 google maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to create a sample project with gmaps4rails gem:
But getting an error:

```
undefined method `gmaps’ for #
Rails.root: /var/www/brandbk
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:46:in `block in create’
app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:45:in `create’
Request
Parameters:
{“utf8″=>”вњ“”,
“authenticity_token”=>”CSpi+VhUe8CtF+4R6zxMEXbB8ofa0QxUF1ntGl+N1Ss=”,
“location”=>{“address”=>”rwr”},
“commit”=>”Create Location”}
```

Like this: http://pastebin.com/zGP9Z7vE
Can anyone help me please?

My models and controllers are valid and same as described on the project wiki.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from here:

```
return true if gmaps4rails_options[:check_process] == true && self.send(gmaps4rails_options[:checker]) == true
```

Basically this line prevents geocoding if:

- it's not requested
- or if it's requested but not already done

So two ways to get rid of it:

- set the `check_process` to false
- add a boolean column to your model named `gmaps` (this could be done with a method as well)

Some more details here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization