# undefined method `gmaps4rails' for... when using gmaps4rails gem Rails 3 postgres local

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I'm attempting to implement  google mapping with the  gmaps4rails gem.  I've followed the tutorial on github here

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/README.rdoc

but when I attempt to render a view I get the error in the title:

undefined method `gmaps4rails' for

According to this thread

[Rails 3 google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103384/rails-3-google-maps)

the answer is to have either check_process => false or to add a gmaps:boolean column to the database.   I've done both with no luck

from console:

```
Event.find(18).gmaps 
=>nil
```

from model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
include Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable


acts_as_gmappable 


def gmaps4rails_address
  #describe how to retrieve the address from your model, if you use directly a db column, you can dry your code, see wiki
 address
end

    end
```

from controller

```
  def index
@events=Event.all
@json = Event.all.to_gmaps4rails
  end
```

from view

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

commenting out the view code gets rid of the error.  displaying only @json in the view renders an empty array.  I also reset the server several times, without any change.

updated with full trace:

```
undefined method `gmaps4rails' for #<#<Class:0x007fb963deb9c0>:0x007fb963dd1778>

Extracted source (around line #18):

15:             <h3 class="twitter_caveat">
16:                 <-- Check twitter feed for updates and details
17:             </h3>
18:             <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
19: 
20:             <% @events=Event.find(:all, :order => :date) %> 
21:             <% unless defined? (old_date) 

Rails.root: /Users/taylorjackson/Desktop/eiweb
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

    app/views/events/index.html.erb:18:in`_app_views_events_index_html_erb___2050852902177216198_70217110523400__1900275664769892622'
    actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `block in _render_template'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:115:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:47:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:55:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:102:in `render_to_string'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:93:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/Users/taylorjackson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__3137438702937572687__process_action__2204161605349298996__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/Users/taylorjackson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/taylorjackson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/taylorjackson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: what's your exact error message?

Comment: Obviously the view helper isn't found yet other methods seem to work... Really weird... Did you reboot your server?

Comment: Had to move on temporarily, but when I came back to it (with no code changes) it worked with no issues.  My only theory is that the postgres server didn't shut down properly until I restarted my computer

Answer (score 0):

I had to move on and leave this issue temporarily, and when I came back to the branch (with no code changes) the gem worked without issue. My only theory is that my local postgres server didn't shut down properly until I restarted my computer in the interim period.